# How can I find specific document and update a value of specific key inside array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a structure like this:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("634aa49f98e3a05346dd2327"),
  filmName: 'Film number 1',
  episodes: [
    {
      episodeName: 'Testing 1',
      slugEpisode: 'testing-1',
      _id: new ObjectId("6351395c17f08335f1dabfc9")
    },
    {
      episodeName: 'Testing 2',
      slugEpisode: 'testing-2',
      _id: new ObjectId("6351399d9a2533b9be1cbab0")
    },
  ],
},
{
  _id: new ObjectId("634aa4cc98e3a05346dd232a"),
  filmName: 'Film number 2',
  episodes: [
    {
      episodeName: 'Something 1',
      slugEpisode: 'something-1',
      _id: new ObjectId("6367cce66d6b85442f850b3a")
    },
    {
      episodeName: 'Something 2',
      slugEpisode: 'something-2',
      _id: new ObjectId("6367cd0e6d6b85442f850b3e")
    },
  ],
}
```

I received 3 fields:

- `_id`: Film _id
- `episodeId`: Episode _id
- `episodeName`: The content I wish to update

I tried to find a specific `Film ID` to get a specific film, and from then on, I pass an `Episode ID` to find the exact episode in the `episodes` array. Then, update the `episodeName` of that specific episode.

Here's my code in NodeJS:

```
editEpisode: async (req, res) => {
    const { _id } = req.params
    const { episodeId, episodeName } = req.body

    try {
        const specificResult = await Films.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id, 'episodes._id': episodeId },
            { episodeName }
        )

        console.log(specificResult)
        res.json({ msg: "Success update episode name" })
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message })
    }
},
```

But what `console.log` display to me is a whole document, and when I check in MongoDB, there was no update at all, does my way of using `findOneAndUpdate` incorrect?

I'm reading this document: [MongooseJS - Find One and Update](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html), they said this one gives me the option to `filter` and `update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB server needs to know which array element to update.  If there is just one array element to update, here's one way you could do it. (I picked a specific element.  You would use your `req.params` and `req.body`.)

```js
db.films.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("634aa4cc98e3a05346dd232a"),
  "episodes._id": ObjectId("6367cd0e6d6b85442f850b3e")
},
{
  "$set": {
    "episodes.$.episodeName": "Something Two"
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2GSdOWmWNpC).

Comment: Thank you, this one really works for me, but may I ask, the `update` is deprecated, I tried to implement it to my VSCode and it said so, it suggest me to use `updateOne`, `updateMany`, or `bulkWrite` instead.

Comment: Yes, use `updateOne` since that's what you're doing.  Unfortunately mongoplayground.net only recognizes `update` and I like to test all my answers if possible. Note that @ambienBeing's answer should work well too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [filtered positional operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered) **`$[<identifier>]`** which essentially finds the element or object (in your case) with a filter condition and updates that.

Query:

```js
const { _id } = req.params
const { episodeId, episodeName } = req.body

await Films.update({
  "_id": _id
},
{
  $set: {
    "episodes.$[elem].episodeName": episodeName
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem._id": episodeId
    }
  ]
})
```

[Check it out here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B0X5NJVn6YM) for example purpose I've put ids as numbers and episode name to update as "UpdatedValue"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is the `[elem]` based on what we self-declare?

Comment: Yes that elem sort of works like an iterator over the array elements, you could name it any other. And then use that name in array filters as well to put the actual filter.